# ¿Como puedo definir la relacion de usuario y tipo de usuario en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy usando mis propias tablas y modelos para el registro de usuarios. El objetivo es que cada usuario pueda tener su informacion de tipo de usuario. Se oye muy sencillo. Para los efectos de la pregunta, solo mostrare el codigo necesario.

Mi modelo `user` se mira asi

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'token',
        'active',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the Person record associated with the user.
     */
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the User Type record associated with the user.
     */ 
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Type::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

Mi modelo `Type` es aun mas sencillo por el momento:

```
class Type extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [ ];

    /**
     * Get the User Type record associated with the user.
     */ 
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

En uno de mis controladores, estoy enviando la informacion de todos los usuarios de esta forma:

```
public function showAllUsers(Request $request)
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('id', 'asc')->with('person', 'type')->where('active', 'yes')->get();

        return response()->json($users, 200);
    }
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es extraño:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "token": "userUniqueToken",
        "active": "yes",
        "persons_id": 3,
        "types_id": 1,
        "images_id": null,
        "created_at": "2021-01-27T06:58:04.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-27T06:58:04.000000Z",
        "person": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Kenny",
            "lastname": "",
            "phone1": "35555555",
            "phone2": "",
            "email": "test1@gmail.com",
            "created_at": "2021-01-27T06:56:31.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-27T06:56:31.000000Z"
        },
        "type": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Empleado",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "token": "userUniqueToken",
        "active": "yes",
        "persons_id": 4,
        "types_id": 1,
        "images_id": null,
        "created_at": "2021-01-27T07:00:11.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-27T07:00:11.000000Z",
        "person": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Josue",
            "lastname": "",
            "phone1": "35555555",
            "phone2": "",
            "email": "test2@gmail.com",
            "created_at": "2021-01-27T06:57:33.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-27T06:57:33.000000Z"
        },
        "type": null
    }
]
```

Si pongo dos, tres o cuatro registros, solo el primero trae toda la informacion del tipo de usuario. ¿Porque a partir del segundo registro el objeto `type` viene vacio?

Comment: No termino de entender, ¿exactamente cuál es el resultado que esperas obtener?

Comment: @BetaM lo que necesito es que todos los usuarios tengan la informacion de su tipo de usuario, aunque sean del mismo tipo.

Comment: ok pero veo dos errores conceptuales. El usuario no tiene hasOne roles. Tiene uno solo en tu modelo, pero esa restricción la inventas tú. Tú puedes en algún caso tener más de un rol? Si la respuesta es sí entonces no uses hasOne. ¿Puede tener un rol varios usuarios con ese rol? Entonces ambos hasMany. Estás imitando un has many con herramientas que no son para eso

Comment: Cual es el `ID` de relacion de tus tablas?(FK) Solo estas asignando `id` a todo, esto hace que el `id` de `user-person-type` sea igual, si te fijas en el primer registro todas las `id` son 1, en el segundo todos son 2 y no encuentra el `type` con id 2 porque no hay

Comment: @ffflabs por ahora, un usuario solo deberia poder tener un type (role). El mismo type (role) si puede pertenecer a varios usuarios. Si uso hasMany en ambos lados, el usuario podria tener varios types (roles).

Comment: @JuanRivera pues no mucho entiendo el comentario, pero en este caso habria que fijarse unicamente en el types_id, que es lo que me interesa, todo lo demas funciona bien. Los id Laravel los reconoce bien automaticamente.

Comment: Si un User sólo puede tener un rol, entonces necesitas un `role_id` en la tabla de usuarios, y el usuario no "tiene" un rol sino que pertenece a un rol, que en sentido inverso abarca muchos usuarios. Teniendo el usuario un `role_id` no se podrá dar que un usuario tenga más de un rol. No es hasOne lo que necesitas. Con `person` sí podría servir dado que hay una llave única a ambos lados (`id`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun lo que veo en tus modelos, las relaciones estan mal hechas, antes de explicarte el porque, veamos las tablas y sus campos que tienes actualmente:

1. user: id, token, active, persons_id, types_id, images_id, timestamps
2. person: id, name, lastname, phone1, phone2, email, timestamps
3. type: id, name, timestamps

Ahora la razon:

1. Modelo User: Estas haciendo 2 relaciones de `hasOne` (person-type). Eso quiere decir, comenzando por `person`, en teoria deberia haber un campo `user_id` por la misma relacion "`hasOne`", pero como vemos en tu tabla, la relacion es de `person->user`, porque en tu tabla `user` hay un campo llamado `persons_id`. Con esto en mente la correcta forma de relacion en tu modelo seria:

```
public function person()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'person_id');
}
public function type()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Type::class, 'types_id');
}
```

Tambien con `type` por lo anterior mencionado

2. Modelo Type: Estas haciendo una relacion `belongsTo`, a tu modelo `user`, eso quiere decir que en teoria, esta relacionado como `user->type`, pero como vemos en tu tabla, la relacion es otra `type->user` porque en tu tabla `user` hay un campo `type_id`, por este motivo la relacion correcta seria `hasOne`

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id');
}
```

Ahora ¿Porque te funciona si no esta correctamente relacionado?

- La respuesta es simple, porque en las relaciones que haces, estas indicando que la llave relacionaria es `id`, cosa que en tus tablas esta como llave primaria y de ahi se fija Laravel. Por eso en tus resultados, el primer registro de `user` tiene como campo `"persons_id": 3,` pero en la relacion de `person` tiene `"person": {"id": 1}`. Porque el id primaria de `user` es "1" y de `person` es "1"

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion. Definitivamente no entendi el comentario, pero esto me ha aclarado todo.